# Include Just one library from 1000 SharePoint online sites in search

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-search

I am struggling to fine the KQL syntax to retrieve search results only from a library name "DPCDocuments"
who's Path is like http://{our tenant}.sharepoint.com/teams/{project number}/DPCDocuments
I tried `path:"https://{siteURL}/DPCDocuments/*"` , `path:"*/DPCDocuments/*"` and other  variation and it did not work.

Also, I get results from `"/PreservationHoldLibrary/"` (the deleted items) and I want to always exclude them. How do I do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1.At the beginning, I search **FolderList.xlsx** file will get three display results.

[image]

2.Edit page (https://tenant.sharepoint.com/.../Pages/results.aspx) >> Edit Search Results web part

3.On the Search Results Panel, click on **Change query** button.

[image]

4.On the Bulid Your Query window, set **property filter**

- **KQL**: SitePath Starts with https://{siteURL}/libraryname/*

[image]

5.Publish page

6.Then, you can get results only from the Documents Library(Shared%20Documents)

[image]

Comment: I am using the [pnp-modern-search](https://microsoft-search.github.io/pnp-modern-search) it should use the same SitePath Starts with https://{siteURL}/libraryname/* But I will check again. Thx